# How do i convert Floor in excel to Unity Mathf?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do i convert Floor in excel to Unity Mathf? I have a procedural equations like this in Excel:

```
= FLOOR(MOD(5, 20) * 0.2, 1)
```

and i want to convert it to C# Script but i can't. I have already tried:

```
float test = Mathf.Floor((5 % 20) * (1 / 5));
```

But it's not what i want. The answer that i want is **1** (Like the result from Excel) but in C# Script it is **0**. Please give me some suggestions and thanks for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1 / 5
```

is an [**integer** division](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#integer-division) with result `0`! Therefore

```
Mathf.Floor((5 % 20) * 0);
```

is obviously also `0`.

---

You should either use a `float` division by simply using a `float` value for at least one of the two operands

```
1f / 5f
```

or why not simply directly use the `float` value

```
0.2f
```

so your line should be

```
float test = Mathf.Floor(5 % 20 * 0.2f);
```

---

Note: If you would like to get the result directly as an `int` value you might want to use [`Mathf.FloorToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html) instead.

---

Just for completeness: Excel's [`FLOOR`](https://support.office.com/article/floor-function-14bb497c-24f2-4e04-b327-b0b4de5a8886) has a second parameter `significance`

> The multiple to which you want to round.

In order to also fake that in your line you would do

```
var result = Mathf.Floor(5 % 20 * 0.2f / significance) * significance;
```

Comment: Thanks for the very clear explaination. I'm appreciate that! My problem solved!